# Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:zipalign (alignApk)

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to create `apk` and sign it, but I am getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:zipalign (alignApk)
```

Anyone can lend me a hand?

Comment: Can you add more output here cause this excerpt is not enough. And best would be to add your pom file.

Comment: Thank you I've solved in my Pom i had defined in <build> tag finalName, so it was renaming the apk file before copying and renaming it for release version i need, so mostly file wasnt found :).